# Getting a set of records at a time in datatables jquery

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using Datatables to put the data i pulled from server in a grid. First it pulls all the records and then put them in grid which is not efficient when number of records is very high.

Question: Does anyone know if it is possible to pull one set of records at a time?

When I click on next button, it should pull next set of records from server. I basically want to trigger an event when next button provided by datatables is clicked.

```
manager.executeQuery(query, function (data) {
 var results = data.results;
                    jsonObj.iTotalRecords = data.results.length;
                    while (jsonObj.aaData.length != 0) {
                        jsonObj.aaData.pop();
                    }
                    $.each(data.results, function (i, c) {
                        var json1 = {
                            PartnerIdNumber: (c.PartnerIdNumber() == null) ? "" : c.PartnerIdNumber,

                        }
                        jsonObj.aaData.push(json1);

                    });
                    $("#PartnerMsg").text('');
                    $("#pardata").dataTable().fnClearTable();
                    $("#pardata").dataTable().fnDestroy();
                    var jobInfoTable = $('#pardata').dataTable({
                        bPaginate: true,
                        bAutoWidth: true,
                        bProcessing: true,
                        bFilter: false,
                        bServerSide: false,
                        aaData: jsonObj.aaData,
                        iTotalRecords: jsonObj.iTotalRecords,
                        iTotalDisplayRecords: jsonObj.iTotalDisplayRecords,
                        aoColumns: [{ "mDataProp": "PartnerIdNumber" }]
                    });

                });
            }

        }
```

This code is able to fetch the data and put that in a grid.

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: Please provide a code example.

Comment: Look for server sided processing like in this php example: http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html